# Real answer appeared in the discussion that followed the original answer

Tags: discussion, answers, accepting

The answer that worked eventually appeared in the discussion with the author of the original answer which wasn't working for me. Should I accept the (original) answer ?

Here is the Question in discussion: [mdframed incompatible with paralist](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126134/)

Comment: Could you give us a link to answer in question? The user who answered originally might update his answer or the user who provided the right comment may post theirselves an answer.

Comment: Ask the `person who made the value adding comment` to `Absorb the  comments into answer` to make it a standalone answer so that you can add a green tick.

Comment: @ Qrrbrbirlbel See "mdframed incompatible with paralist".

Comment: @ texenthusiast That would indeed work but might be a bit misleading. See "mdframed incompatible with paralist".

Comment: Usually most people who work on a daily basis maintain a latest TeXLive on all their OS and even on http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic it's mentioned to post Q (bug related) after updating distro but nevertheless TL 2012 is not too old for Q & A so an `Addendum/Correction` by to current answer by Medina looks fine and gives the full pledged answer as per TL 2013 which is mentioned in answer also. You can accept the answer now. Of course distro version is a personal choice and as per comfort :).

Comment: All done. Thanks to everybody.

Comment: For future reference, in case the title changes: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126134/

Answer (score 3):

As [Qrrbrbirlbel](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16595/qrrbrbirlbel) and myself pointed out: converting the comments to answer

> Comment to the @user-name who gave the *Real answer* to `Absorb the comments inside answer` with an *Addendum/Correction* to the existing answer as [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina) has already [done](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126136/15717).

In this way all details(in comments) are stored well with version control/edits and becomes a standalone answer irrespective of any missing comments (Incase so..).